# What is the proper way to automate SSH/local command?

Tags: ssh, git

I have gitolite on a Centos 5.5 box - when a repository is updated, I need to send a command to my bug tracking appliance to get the new commands. Right now, I have the following command working:

`ssh bugserver -f 'cd /etc/repos/gitrepo && git pull origin prod && exit'`

This seems a little dirty, though. Is there a better way to execute this sync?

Comment: Why do you find this dirty? You can omit the redundant `&& exit` at the end, but after that, what do you hope to do better?

Comment: I wasn't really sure if this was the correct way to do it, but judging by the responses, it looks like it is the least complicated method. Also, why can I omit the `&& exit`? Wouldn't it keep the SSH session open?

Comment: When ssh is used to pass commands, it automatically closes the client session when the commands complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considering the options, I decided to modify the command (removed the `&& exit`) and left it as is for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a Makefile.

```
sync:
↹ssh bugserver -f 'cd /etc/repos/gitrepo && git pull origin prod && exit'
```

Then run it.

```
$ make sync
```

Note that `↹` is actually a tab character. See your editor's documentation for how to enter it (but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> may work).

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to script something up using [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect), but that may be over complicated for something this simple. I've used it in the past to login to a remote power switch and cycle a given port, so I believe you could probably use it for this application as well.

Comment: you can use expect to do anything that requires repeatable, consistent, interaction.

Comment: Very true. I was just thinking that this may be easier to use a bash alias or something simple like that. I am a big fan of expect now though; made my life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two additional solutions, both assume you are using bash shell. The first is to create a function to perform the task, place that function in your ~/.bashrc file:

```
function bugsync() {
    ssh bugserver -f 'cd /etc/repos/gitrepo && git pull origin prod'
}
```

The second is to create an alias:

```
alias bugsync="ssh bugserver -f 'cd /etc/repos/gitrepo && git pull origin prod'"
```

Note that you don't need to specify the '&& exit' part of the command.